# matlab remove duplicate row( unordered)

Tags: matlab, matrix, duplicates

For example:

```
A = [1,3; 3,1; 2,10; 10,2; 3,4; 3,4; 5,8; 9,3; 1,8]
```

and my target is

```
A = [1,3; 2,10; 3,4; 5,8; 9,3; 1,8]
```

the duplicate one,（ordered and unordered) need be removed.

I have tried unique, but it doesn't work for the unordered row.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 4):

You can [`sort`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) the rows individually then use [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and look at the **second** output to determine the first time you see a particular occurrence in the matrix. You would also look at the rows as individual samples and you also want a **stable** unique result to preserve the ordering of what you see in the matrix `A`.  Sorting allows you to consider each row in an unordered fashion. Basically, the second output would be used to index into the rows of `A` so that you extract out what you need in the original matrix, not the sorted one. The result would be the removal of duplicate rows ignoring the order of entries as they appear in them:

```
[~,id,~] = unique(sort(A, 2), 'rows', 'stable');
out = A(id, :);
```

Using the input you have provided, we get:

```
>> [~,id,~] = unique(sort(A, 2), 'rows', 'stable');
>> out = A(id, :);

>> out

out =

     1     3
     2    10
     3     4
     5     8
     9     3
     1     8
```